# run exe and terminate it if some time passes - in php

Tags: php, exe

I have `.exe` file. I want to run it and after some time (let's say after 1.5secs) passes terminate `.exe` and report about `time limit exceed`. I spent 2 days to find this out, but no success.

P.S. I can't use `pthread` extension. I am having trouble in installing it. :(

**EDIT**: My problem now is when I `proc_terminate()` the `$process` php script stops waiting for `run.exe`, but `run.exe` is still running (I can see it in the task manager). My php script :

```
<pre>
<?php

$descriptorspec = array(
    1 => array('pipe', 'w')
    );
$process = proc_open("C:/wamp/www/yet-another-online-judge/run.exe", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    usleep(2.5*1000000); // wait 2.5 secs

    $status = proc_get_status($process);
    if ($status['running'] == true) {
        proc_terminate($process);
        echo "VERDICT : TLE\n";
    } else {
        echo "EXIT CODE : {$status['exitcode']}\n";
        echo "OUTPUT :\n";

        while (!feof($pipes[1]))
            echo fgets($pipes[1]);

        fclose($pipes[1]);
        proc_close($process);
    }
}

?>
</pre>
```

run.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "1+1=3";
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

if you dont understand C++: run.exe outputs `1+1=3` to stdout and then enters an infinte loop.

So is there a way to actually terminate run.exe ??

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389006/how-to-terminate-a-process?

Comment: Thanks, I read it. But now I have another problem, see EDIT.

Comment: Hmm, i am not that good with php to help you out here...

Comment: On the other hand... You could also use a C++ program as proxy... I'll admit, it's really dirty but if you write a start.exe wich returns a procces id and a terminate.exe wich kills a process id/handle then you're there. There are loads of examples on how to kill a process in c++. You might experience some security issues though...